# variable does not exist anonymous console

Tags: apex, developer-console

i have one method in my class controller and when i try to call it from the anonymous console i received this error message:  ***variable does not exist: email (ad example)***.

This is my code in the anonymous console:

```
    String x = NameOfMyClassController.checkList(email, tel);
    System.debug('=====>'+ x);
```

this is my method in my controller class:

```
public List<String_result> checkList(String email,String tel){
    List<String_Input> contactDeletedList= null;
    List<String_Result> result = null;
    Set<String> contactInp=null;


    if (!String.isBlank(email) && !String.isBlank(tel))
    {   
        contactInp = new set<String>{email,tel};
        contactDeletedList= new List<String_Input>();
        contactDeletedList.add(new String_Input(contactInp));
        result = NameOfmyClass.NameOfmyMethod(contactDeletedList);
    }
    System.debug('====>' + result);
    return result;
}
```

I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: To call your method from your class in anonymus apex, you still need to submit parameters. for example **String x = NameOfMyClassController.checkList('some email', 'some tel');**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message is pretty straightforward. Did you initialize email variable??

EDITED: Here's example

```
NameOfMyClassController controller = new NameOfMyClassController();
String tel = 'yourPhoneNumber';
String email ='yourEmail@hotmail.com';     
String x = controller.checkList(email, tel);
System.debug('=====>'+ x);
```

Comment: i tried it but sure i have wrong, can you write me one example please?

Comment: i tried, now the error is: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: NameOfMyClassController.checkList(String, String)

Comment: checkList is not static so you need to create instance of NameOfMyClassController.